# Type a curly bracket in VS Code HTML Emmet

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm trying to write an Emmet abbreviation for an HTML document in which I'm using a lot of LaTex. I am using VS Code. Is there a way to do this?

Emmet (this is what I need help with):

```
"math" : "math>{$$\begin{align} \end{align}$$}"
```

Expected HTML output (the `|` represents my cursor):

```
<math>
    $$\begin{align}|\end{align}$$
</math>
```

Turns out the `snippets.json` file won't accept curly braces. I've tried escaping using the backslash `\{`, quotes `'{'`, and double braces `{{`. No  good.

Comment: just define a regular snippet

Comment: @rioV8, that's ultimately what I ended up doing. See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own snippet for HTML inside of VSCode. Paste this into html.json snippets inside of VS. You can use ctrl+shift+p or cmd+shift+p and search for Preferences: Configure User Snippets then select html.json

```
"Math Snippet": {
        "prefix": "math",
        "body": [
          "<math>",
          "    $$\\begin{align}${0}\\end{align}$$",
          "</math>"
        ],
        "description": "Custom HTML snippet for VSCode"
      }
```

Once you save, you can now type math and use tab like normal on any .html files in VScode

Comment: This does the job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be through a programmatic approach. Basically you use JavaScript to change the math elements `textContent` property to the value that is saved in a variable

**Here is the code:**

```js
let math_str = '$$\begin{align}|\end{align}$$';

const elem = document.querySelector('#math');

elem.textContent = math_str;
```

```html
<math id='math'>

</math>
```

Comment: But this works at runtime right? I need it while editing